# Bootstrap 3.0 : added 2 sliders to home page both conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Solved**    For first slider  i changed name  :carousel-example-generic to carousel-example-generic_1 to differentiate and that solved my problem

i am using  2 bootstrap sliders on my home  page , problem is that  main 0slider is working fine but when i click left or right arrow for second slider that also slides  images for first slider , so will someone please guide me how do i fix it my code is like this

```
           <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
           <div class="carousel-inner rightslider" role="listbox"  >
             <div class="item active">
                <div align="middle">
                    <img src="http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/iron/y/c/t/pigeon-favourite-750-w-favourite-750-w-400x400-imadzkdzyqx6yd9r.jpeg" width="80%" height="100" alt="" title="" border="0">
                </div>
                <div align="middle" class="coupon_title">
                    <a class="coupon_title" href="http://aaa.php?id=8&amp;c=65" target="_blank"><b>Pigeon Favourite 750 W Dry Iron</b></a>
                </div>
                <div class="coupon_price" align="middle"> 
                    <div class="price-old">&#8377;645</div>
                    <div class="price-new">&#8377;399</div>
                </div>
                 <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-default " href="">Use Coupon
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                    </a>
                 </div><br>
             </div>
```

Comment: Check this: `<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` and the `href` of the controls should be the ID of the carousel. (If you add a fiddle, i'll show you)

Comment: @OfirBaruch code is same for both sliders please  let me know what to change ,

Comment: You need to change the names so they'll be unique for each slider.

Comment: i already changed  thank u :)

Comment: Can I write it as an answer if it helped you?

Comment: sure  u can as u did help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the getbootstrap manual for the [`slider's component usage`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage):

> Carousels require the use of an id on the outermost container (the
>   .carousel) for carousel controls to function properly. When adding
>   multiple carousels, or when changing a carousel's id, be sure to
>   update the relevant controls.

So, if the following code is for one slider:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

  <!-- Controls -->
</div>
```

For the other slide, you should have a different id, for instance:
`id="carousel-example-generic2"`.

Take in mind that you should use a more relevant name, for instance: "news-carousel" or "main-slideshow".

In case you're having `controls` in your slider, be sure you're updating the `href` values so they'll point to the relevant slider.

```
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" [<--] role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" [<--] role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```